# onClick por InnerHTML React?

Tags: react, front-end

Estou tentando criar uma `img` com o Evento de `onClick` no `React` mas está imprimindo o código dessa forma na Web.

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Meu codigo inner está assim:

```
 coluna4.innerHTML = `<img onClick={() => this.apagar(${key})} class='ml-6'  width='30' height='30' src='https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1489/PNG/128/rubbishbin_102620.png' alt='Excluir' title='Excluir' />`
```

Minha função que recebe parâmetro:

```
apagar = (key) => {
    console.log(key)

}
```

Exemplo Código Completo

```
export default class Product extends Component {
    state = {
        produtos: [],

    }

    componentDidMount() {

        for (var i = 0; i < sessionStorage.length; i++) {
            var key = sessionStorage.key(i)
            var session = sessionStorage.getItem(key);
            var split = session.split('-');
            var tabela = document.getElementById('tb-cart');
            var linha = tabela.insertRow(-1);
            //Adiciona dua coluna na linha criada <td></td> <td></td>
            var coluna1 = linha.insertCell(0);
            var coluna2 = linha.insertCell(1);
            var coluna3 = linha.insertCell(2);
            var coluna4 = linha.insertCell(3);
            //Inclui o valor do campo do formulário em sua respectiva coluna
            coluna1.innerHTML = split[1];
            coluna2.innerHTML = split[0];
            coluna3.innerHTML = split[2];
            coluna4.innerHTML = `<img onClick={() => this.apagar(${key})} class='ml-6'  width='30' height='30' src='https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1489/PNG/128/rubbishbin_102620.png' alt='Excluir' title='Excluir' />`
        }
    }

    inserirCarrinho = async (id) => {
        const response = await api.get(`/livros/listar/${id}`)
        sessionStorage.setItem(id, response.data.descricao + "-" + response.data.nome + "-" + response.data.valor)
    }

    apagar =  (key) => {
        console.log(key)

    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                <Table id="tb-cart" className="container" striped bordered hover>
                    <thead class="thead-dark">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Nome livro</th>
                            <th>Descrição</th>
                            <th>Valor</th>
                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                </Table>

            </div >
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `coluna4.innerHTML` já tem comandos errados logo de cara se percebe que você deve ta iniciando, tem que ser feito com os comandos do `React`, gostaria de ajudar, mas, como não sei todo o seu código fica complicado.

Comment: Vou comentar o meu codigo

Comment: Sabe aquela parte onde tem o método `componentDidMount()` se tem que fazer isso com comando do `React`, precisa aprender a maneira correta ... entendeu o problema?

Comment: Ainda não cara, `componentDidMount()` não e do React?

Comment: Eu resolvi fazer um exemplo ... é só testar é assim que preenche uma tabela e qualquer elemento pois o `React` precisa controlar os estados desse componente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando `React` da maneira errada, e ai não tem o resultado esperado que é uma montagem simples de uma tabela, vamos para um exemplo para que entenda o que deve fazer:

```js
class Product extends React.Component {
  state = {
    produtos: [],
  }
  componentDidMount() {
      const items = [
        {
          nome: 'nome 1',
          descricao: 'descricao 1',
          valor: 125.55
        },
        {
          nome: 'nome 2',
          descricao: 'descricao 2',
          valor: 200.55
        }
      ];
      this.setState({produtos: items});
  }
  apagar = key => {
    console.log(key);
  }
  render() {
    const { produtos } = this.state;
    return ( 
      <div> 
        <table className="table">
          <tr>
            <th>Nome Livro</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Valor</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>       
          { produtos.map((p, i) => (
            <tr key={i}>
              <td>{p.nome}</td>
              <td>{p.descricao}</td>
              <td>{p.valor}</td>
              <td><img onClick={() => this.apagar(i)} class='ml-6'  width='30' height='30' src='https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/1489/PNG/128/rubbishbin_102620.png' alt='Excluir' title='Excluir' 
 style={{cursor:'pointer'}}/></td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < Product / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root">Aguarde ...</div>
```

Comment: Eu tinha feito dessa forma no começo, mas quando eu ia inserir outro produto ele sobrescrevia o antigo.

Comment: @GustavoHenrique por isso depende a forma como você está fazendo, se percebeu ai a forma correta de se fazer o componente renderiza as informações, então siga essa lógica. Como você está fazendo o `insert`? se a resposta te serviu com solução por favor aceita como resposta da sua pergunta...