# Problema de "setState" usando React

Tags: javascript, array, react

Tenho um código em React que usa o *hook* `useState` dessa maneira:

```
const [tarefas, setTarefas] = useState([]);
```

É um código de lista de tarefas, toda vez que removo um projeto tenho que atualizar o projeto de cada tarefa, estava tentando fazer assim:

```
setTarefas(tarefas.map(tarefa => {
    if (tarefa.projeto > id) {
      tarefa.projeto--;
    }
    
    return tarefa;
}
```

Sendo que o `id` é o `id` do `projeto` que esta sendo excluído. O problema é, ele não atualiza a propriedade `projeto` da `tarefa`, continua como se essa parte do código não existisse. Alguém tem alguma ideia do que pode ser?

Logo antes de tentar fazer isso, eu faço o `filter` no array por meio dessa linha:

```
setTarefas(tarefas.filter(tarefa => tarefa.projeto !== id));
```

O que na real esta acontecendo é que ele parece que não filtra, as tarefas não somem. Ele filtra apenas se eu tirar o método que muda o `id`.

Comment: o que você quer fazer fiquei em duvida?

Comment: você por favor coloque o layout de cada item da tarefa!

Comment: eu quero no caso trocar o id do objeto tarefa se ele for maior que o id que eu passei

Comment: projeto: projetoAtual,
nome: tarefa.nome,
data: tarefa.data,
prioridade: tarefa.prioridade,
feito: tarefa.feito

Answer (score 1):

O problema está em que precisas de retorna um novo objecto com a propriedade alterada. No React não deves manipular directamente o estado deves calcular um novo estado com base no actual. Tenta assim.

```js
setTarefas(tarefas.map(tarefa => {
    let novaTarefa = {...tarefa}
    if (novaTarefa.projeto > id) {
      novaTarefa.projeto--;
    }
    
    return novaTarefa;
})
```

Comment: esqueci de falar que logo antes de executar essa linha, eu faco um filter() no meu array de tarefas pra depois fazer essa mudanço. O que acontece é que ele nao ta filtrando, nao ta removendo as tarefas

Comment: Mas claro ele não vai remover apenas decrementar a variável.

Comment: mas eu mando filtrar o meu array "tarefas" de acordo com o id que chega como parametro da função, o id do projeto no caso. Se a tarefa tem a propriedade "projeto" igual o id, ela é removida do array, senao ela fica.

Comment: setTarefas(tarefas.filter(tarefa => tarefa.projeto !== id));  <=== desse jeito, e logo depois eu faço o que coloquei na pergunta, mudo o projeto pra -1 se for maior que o id. So que quand vou ver,a  tarefa nao é removida

Comment: Consegues mandar o código por pastebin ou repl.it para perceber melhor o que estás a fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Pelos comentários, entendi que sua duvida é remover um item de uma lista, se sim, o exemplo logo abaixo pode facilitar o seu entendimento, exemplo:

```js
function App() {
  const [tarefas, setTarefas] = React.useState([
    {'id': 1, 'desc': 'Tarefa 1'},
    {'id': 2, 'desc': 'Tarefa 2'},
    {'id': 3, 'desc': 'Tarefa 3'},
    {'id': 4, 'desc': 'Tarefa 4'},
    {'id': 5, 'desc': 'Tarefa 5'},
  ])
  const styleListType = {
    listStyleType: "none",
    marginTop: 10
  };
  const onRemove = (id) => {
    setTarefas(tarefas.filter(item => item.id !== id));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
      {tarefas && tarefas.map((tarefa, index) => (
        <li style={styleListType}>
          <button onClick={() => onRemove(tarefa.id)}>Excluir</button> 
          {' ' + tarefa.desc}
        </li>)
      )}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

sendo que o método `onRemove` remove o item da lista com um determinado filtro.

Mais alguns exemplos e assuntos relacionados:

- [Duvida sobre padrão classe React](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426304/duvida-sobre-padr%c3%a3o-classe-react/426335#426335)
- [Melhor pattern para gerenciar estado de componentes React com Hooks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443787/melhor-pattern-para-gerenciar-estado-de-componentes-react-com-hooks/443821#443821)
- [onClick por InnerHTML React?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/418636/onclick-por-innerhtml-react/418642#418642)
- [Compartilhar state react hooks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/453548/compartilhar-state-react-hooks/453601#453601)
- [Exibindo dados com React JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/420637/exibindo-dados-com-react-js/420642#420642)
- [Não consigo utilizar o defaultProps em React](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427198/n%c3%a3o-consigo-utilizar-o-defaultprops-em-react/427200#427200)
- [Contador não atualiza dados na pagina usando ReactJS e useState(), somente quando coloco um console.log() que consigo ver o resultado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/441766/contador-n%c3%a3o-atualiza-dados-na-pagina-usando-reactjs-e-usestate-somente-quand/441844#441844)