# Estado da array não atualizado com sort

Tags: javascript, react

Estou puxando um array com os repositórios de um usuário no github e preciso arrumar a ordenação de acordo com o número de estrelas, tendo a opção de crescente e decrescente.

Pensei em: quando o usuário clicar no botão vai ser chamada uma função que aplica um `sort()` e depois altera o estado usando o `useState`. Testei isso usando um array hardcoded e funcionou, porém, nos dados puxados da api não ta rolando. Alguma ideia de como resolver isso?

Aqui o código que está puxando os dados:

```js
const [repoList, setRepoList] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        ` https://api.github.com/users/${id}/repos`
      );
      setRepoList(response.data);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);
```

Aqui o código da função de `sort`

```js
 function lowerStarOrder() {
    repoList.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a.stargazers_count > b.stargazers_count) {
        return 1;
      }
      if (a.stargazers_count < b.stargazers_count) {
        return -1;
      }
      if (a.stargazers_count === b.stargazers_count) {
        return 0;
      }
    });

    setRepoList(repoList);
  }
```

e aqui o código JSX

```js
{repoList.map((repo) => (
    <RepositoryHeader
       key={repo.id}
       github={repo.html_url}
       details={`/details/${repo.full_name}`}
       repositoryName={repo.name}
       language={repo.language}
        value={repo.stargazers_count}
     />
 ))}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu resolvi fazer um exemplo mínimo de ordenação pela campo `value`, onde sua ordem começa do menor para o maior e ao pressionar o botão muda do maior para o menor valor:

```js
function App() {
  const [tarefas, setTarefas] = React.useState([
    {'id': 1, 'desc': 'Tarefa 1', 'value': 5},
    {'id': 2, 'desc': 'Tarefa 2', 'value': 3},
    {'id': 3, 'desc': 'Tarefa 3', 'value': 4},
    {'id': 4, 'desc': 'Tarefa 4', 'value': 1},
    {'id': 5, 'desc': 'Tarefa 5', 'value': 2},
  ]);
  const [sort, setSort] = React.useState('A');
  const changeSort = () => setSort(sort === 'A' ? 'D': 'A');
  const torder = tarefas.sort((a,b) => {
     const v1 = a.value;
     const v2 = b.value;
     return sort === 'A' ? v1 - v2 : v2 - v1;
 });
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
      {torder
        .map((t, i) => (<li>{t.desc} - value: {t.value}</li>))
      }
      </ul>
      <button onClick={() => changeSort() }>
      {sort === 'A' ? 'Descendente': 'Ascendente'}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Mais alguns exemplos e assuntos relacionados:

- [Duvida sobre padrão classe React](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/426304/duvida-sobre-padr%c3%a3o-classe-react/426335#426335)
- [Melhor pattern para gerenciar estado de componentes React com Hooks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/443787/melhor-pattern-para-gerenciar-estado-de-componentes-react-com-hooks/443821#443821)
- [onClick por InnerHTML React?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/418636/onclick-por-innerhtml-react/418642#418642)
- [Compartilhar state react hooks](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/453548/compartilhar-state-react-hooks/453601#453601)
- [Exibindo dados com React JS](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/420637/exibindo-dados-com-react-js/420642#420642)
- [Não consigo utilizar o defaultProps em React](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/427198/n%c3%a3o-consigo-utilizar-o-defaultprops-em-react/427200#427200)
- [Contador não atualiza dados na pagina usando ReactJS e useState(), somente quando coloco um console.log() que consigo ver o resultado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/441766/contador-n%c3%a3o-atualiza-dados-na-pagina-usando-reactjs-e-usestate-somente-quand/441844#441844)

Comment: Muito obrigado! Funcionou perfeitamente!

Pelo que entendi eu não estava passando uma condicional para a atualização do componente, coisa que a sua variável `sort`faz. Obrigado pelo material de referência também, foi de grande ajuda!